# Can I replicate an Azure VM while the said VM is still running? or Will the VM stop while replicating?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, replication, infrastructure

I have and Azure VM which is quite critical as it is running services. I wanted to replicate that VM.

My question is, Can I replicate an Azure VM while the said VM is still running? or Will the VM be stopped while replicating?

And also, I wanted to know, If the replicated VM will automatically be up when the primary VM will suffer outage? or should I manually start it?

Regards,

Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can using Azure Recovery Services, it will replicate while running. I think failover is manual, but you can write some automation bit that will do it for you